# Deserialize Json to Object in a handler

Tags: c#, json, handler, deserialization

I have a simple class:

```
public class site
        {
            public string URL { get; set; }
        }
```

That exists within a http handler. Currently I am posting json to this handler and trying to deserialize it to get the URL out of the string. I am however having a problem with the deserialize part of it.

I have a string "jsonString" that has the json formatted like so:

```
[{"URL":"http://www.google.com/etc/"}]
```

Here is my code for the deserialize:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string jsonString = String.Empty;

        HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        site currSite = new site();
        currSite = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<site>(jsonString);

        //set response types
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;


       //send response 
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsonSerializer.Serialize(currSite.URL));
```

I am then trying to send a response using currSite.URL however it is failing. What am I missing here? I am reasonably confident it is at the deserialize part because if I send a response of jsonString instead of currSite.URL it will work.

Comment: What's the error you receive and on what line?

Comment: Can you debug and see currSite be filled with data after deserialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json string shows that it's an array, not a single entity. You should deserialize it as so:

```
var result = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<site[]>(jsonString);
```

And `result[0].Url` should contain what you are looking for.

**Update**

Adding sample code:

```
 string json = @"[{""URL"":""http://www.google.com/etc/""}]";

 JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var result = js.Deserialize<site[]>(json);
 Console.WriteLine(result[0].URL);
```

Prints: 
    http://www.google.com/etc/

Comment: This put me on the correct path, I ended up changing the json that was being posted to a single entity and my code works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to send back the URL as the response (just the string) there's no need to serialize the value. Just pass `currSite.URL` to the `Write` method.

Otherwise, I'm guessing you should serialize the whole `currSite` object for the response rather than just the URL. It all depends on what kind of response the caller is expecting (which you haven't specified).